# Calamity vs Catastrophe

Tags: etymology, differences

Catastrophe - 
An event causing great and usually sudden damage or suffering; a disaster.
an environmental catastrophe

Calamity - 
An event causing great and usually sudden damage or suffering; a disaster.
emergency measures may be necessary in order to avert a calamity

Is the only difference between these two words is where they originated/etymology?

**NOTE**

calamity (n.) Look up calamity at Dictionary.com
early 15c., from Middle French calamite (14c.), from Latin calamitatem (nominative calamitas) "damage, loss, failure; disaster, misfortune, adversity," **origin obscure.** Early etymologists associated it with calamus "straw" (see shawm); but it is perhaps from a lost root preserved in incolumis "uninjured," from PIE *kle-mo-, from base *kel- "to strike, cut" (see hilt).

Comment: I think the word *calamity* puts more emphasis on  emotional impact on people (e.g. grief) than *catastrophe* does.

Comment: Just a note, calamity seems to always by used in the future/present tense. ie "to prevent a calamity" or "this is a calamity" but (as mikhailcazi might have inadvertently pointed out) never in the past tense ie. "it was a calamity".

Comment: @Edward - Not in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

'*Calamity*' is generally used to refer to only large-scale natural/man-made disasters.

However, '*catastrophe*' isn't limited to that usage.
It isn't uncommon to use catastrophe in the following way:

> "The wedding-party was a catastrophe."

I don't think *calamity* is used in that manner.

Additionally, 'catastrophe' has another meaning. I don't think it's used very often, but the ending of a tragic play is called a 'catastrophe'.

According to Oxford Dictionaries:

> the denouement of a drama, esp. a classical tragedy.

Comment: +1 for the alternative meaning, interesting but "I don't think calamity is used in that manner." i understand that *it just isn't*, but i was looking for an explanation as to why, maybe a reference?

Comment: *Katastrophe* was a technical term (meaning, roughly, 'fatal denouement')  in Greek drama, which was taken as a European model at least until Shakespeare (and into the 19th century in France, for example). *Catastrophe* thus originated as a precise term in literary criticism; 'disaster' is just a transferred meaning.  My classics teacher insisted that a catastrophe has to be unexpected; so an England batting collapse can be calamitous but not catastrophic.

Comment: "catastrophe has to be unexpected", nice. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

In catastrophe there is sudden and usually large scale damage to property;
In caseof calamity, there is loss of life and human suffering coupled with damages to property

Comment: Please add a reference (link) or two, to back up the info you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Calamity refers to human suffering and anguish caused by negligence or other mismanagement of a proper response to events that are catastrophic in nature. Or as Oliver Hardy used to opine, "Here's another fine mess you've gotten us into".

Comment: This post would be improved by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.